# Does a hybrid or mountain bike with a 24" diameter rim use a 24" tube and 24" tire?

Tags: size

I tried to search this at length but I have not found an answer. Should a bigger size be gotten or am I over thinking this?

Comment: When bicycle wheel sizes are discussed, the size in inches usually refers to the approximate outside diameter of the wheel with the tyre fitted.

Comment: When buying a new tyre it’s useful to have the old one to compare

Answer (score 4):

If you had a rim that actually measured 24 inches in diameter then that would be about 609mm in diameter. This would [seem to indicate](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html) that you had some "Rare Danish size" of rim that would be very hard to find a modern tire for, and is probably not what you are looking for.

If you have a "24 inch mountain bike" then it would most likely have a rim that measures 507mm across or about 20 inches across. Tires sold for this size are quite common and would be sold under 24 x 2.0 or some other variation on the second number to signify the width of the tire.

If in doubt, take the bike down to you local bike shop and ask them for advice. They should be able to instruct you as to the right size to buy. Measuring rims can be difficult because you have to measure inside the rim at the "bead seat" (where the tire rests when mounted), and not at the edge of the rim.

Comment: Measuring rims is not difficult, you just need a length of inelastic cord and a pie, or what was it called...